# Maze screensaver on old Unix computers

Tags: screensaver

I used to use unix computers in the 90's for building GIS systems. There used to be a screen saver which consited of a maze that filled the screen. Then the computer would logically solve the maze with a shaded path, a lighter shade for the wrong decisions and a darker shade for the correct decisions, and eventually showing the completed solution.

I would love to see this screen saver again, and even get it for my windows computer.

Does anyone remember it?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but the only "screen saver" that actually saves your screen is the Energy Star blank mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you saw this on an older system, chances that it was running [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/). You can see its [standard collection](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/screenshots/); there's a maze one which looks like what you describe.

Note that it was common for people to install their own screensavers, for the decorative appeal. So this could have been something added locally, perhaps even something coded locally. However, it's likely that they would have used [similar algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm).

Comment: Yep, I think that was what I was looking for. Thanks @Gilles